# Get POST data from request

Tags: node.js, slack

I need to extract POST data from a request I'll receive (using Slack Slash Commands, I basically want to check the channel where the command's been called and only execute it in some particular channels).

I'm relatively new to NodeJs, so I'm usually quite lost around requests and the like, precise help is welcome.

(Small detail: when trying out different methods, I noticed that if I requested say, *response.js* from Slack, Slack wouldn't display the same logs that I see in shell, rather displaying the entire code in chat. Am I doing something wrong?)

Edit: I'm using Express.

Edit 2 : added `request.js` and `response.js`

`request.js` :

```
var request = require('request');
var requestData = {
    "token" : "XXXXXXXX",
    "team_id" : "XXXXX"
}
var options = {
    url : 'http://XX.XXX.XX.XX/request/response.js',
    method : 'POST',
    json : requestData
}

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    console.log("requesting");
    if (err)
        console.log("error, mate");
    else
        console.log("no worries");
})
```

`response.js` :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/request/response.js', function (req, res) {
    var post_body = req.body;
    console.log(post_body);
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("listening");
})
```

Comment: Do you use a NodeJS framework, like Express for example ?

Comment: Yep, Express! Edited the main post.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far ? And your express version

Answer (score 6):

To read POST data, you'll need *body-parser*. First you install it using the command line :

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

And then, you include it in your main app.js file :

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

And finally to use it in a *POST* route, you use `req.body` :

```
app.post('/api/postRoute', function(req, res) {
    var post_body = req.body;
    // Return the POST message
    res.send(post_body);
});
```

Your full response.js should look like that :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/postRoute', function(req, res) {
    var post_body = req.body;
    // Return the POST message
    res.send(post_body);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

Then you start it from the command line using :

```
node response.js
```

And then you POST requests to the URL :
    http://localhost:3000/api/postRoute

Comment: I used your method and I'm trying to find a way of checking if it works. I submitted a POST request to my response.js file (which contains your code), but neither the `res.send` nor a `console.log` prompted any text? How can I verify the request actually goes through ?

Comment: Do you get a response on your browser side ?

Comment: And what do you mean by `Submitted a POST request to my response.js file` ? You shouldn't post _to_ the file but to a nodejs express server running that file... Are you running `node response.js` before trying your POST request ?

Comment: Thank you. I don't think the localhost will do the trick though, my code is on a VM I connect to with ssh.

Comment: So you can simply replace the `localhost` part with the IP of your VM :)

Comment: I still don't see anything when doing this, I updated the main post with both my .js files. (Thanks for putting up with me)

Comment: You need to use the port 3000 because the express server listens to port 3000 only ( `app.listen(3000` ) . So the url should be `http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:3000/request/response.js`

Comment: I did the changes, and now when I run `request.js` it just stands there doing nothing, no `requesting`. I can display a `console.log()` before the `request()` call, but anything below that just doesn't appear.

Comment: did you first run `node response.js` ?

Comment: The code works, I hosted a version (https://runkit.com/sharkoz/test-post-request) that you can test by replacing your url by : https://test-post-request-qpqycylp5zoh.runkit.sh/api/postRoute

Comment: I tried replacing `'/request/response.js'` with `https://test-post-request-qpqycylp5zoh.runkit.sh/api/postRoute` in my request, it displays `yo` but nothing else. Should I define something as the `body` in my request, specifically?

Comment: You have all the code, tested and working, I can't see what could possibly go wrong now :) I have no idea where this 'yo' comes from... For me the URL returns exactly what you POST to it so I imagine that's what you are sending somehow. Make sure you understand how Express work, and try their Getting Started guide (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) if you're still confused.

Comment: (The `yo` was a debug message in my own code, no worries)
And yeah I'll try to go through a more detailed tutorial, I seem to be missing something obvious